# Stop program entirely if condition is met within a function C++

Tags: c++

Currently working on a simple Triangle classifier program in C++ and its working quite well, with the exception of one or two things.

Okay, so I have four functions, one for handling errors such as values of less than zero being entered or lengths being entered which do not allow for a triangle to be physically possible; one for the classifier which determines what type of triangle it is depending on the values provided; one to calculate the area which uses the sides as double values to calculate the area using Heron's formula, and finally, the main function, which calls all these functions in this order with the sides being given to them as their arguments so that the if statement can follow them through.

My issue is this, when a user enters side lengths of 0, it prints the error message that the user has entered values which are equal to zero, but then it prints that its an equilateral triangle. What would I have to change so that the program completely stops when a condition is met within the if statement? I think the problem is, the condition works properly, but because I am calling the Classifier function right after the ExceptionHandling, it prints that its an equilateral triangle.

I also want to setup a loop which would let the user try and enter a value again if they entered a value which caused a condition to be met in the ExceptionHandling function, however I've tried setting up a while loop which just causes an infinite loop.

I've provided some code snippets below, however, I can't post the full code because its an assignment and I don't want anyone else to find it. :p

```
...

void ExceptionHandling(double side1, double side2, double side3)
{
    if (side1 < 1 || side2 < 1 || side3 < 1)
    {
        cout << "Error: All values must be greater than zero." << endl;
    }
}

double Classifier(double side1, double side2, double side3)
{
    if (side1 == side2 && side2 == side3)
    {
        cout << "This would be classified as an equilateral triangle." << endl;
    }

...

int main()
{
    double side1;
    cout << "Enter the longest side: ";
    cin >> side1;

        ...

    ExceptionHandling(side1, side2, side3);
    Classifier(side1, side2, side3);
    Area(side1, side2, side3);
}
```

Would appreciate a dumbed down explanation, as I'm quite keen to know.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make your `exceptionHandling` routine return a value. `if(exceptionHandling(side1, side2, side3)== -1) return -1;` would be one way. Figure out the details from here, can you?

Comment: Call [`_exit()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit.2.html)

Comment: @Floris Pardon my ignorance, but I didn't quite get what you meant by exceptionhandling routine return a value... do you mean modifying the actual ExceptionHandling function or the call of the function?

Comment: @VladLazarenko Doesn't seem to work, throws an error at me:

'error: ‘_exit’ was not declared in this scope
   _exit()'

This is when I add '_exit()' to the end of the if statement condition or the end of the whole block of if statements, I guess it's looking for something in those brackets as it takes arguments I presume, but there aren't any..? (Please correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit on invalid input (as opposed to making the user try again) then what you should do is something like:

```
int main() {
  ...
  if (not ValidInput(side1, side2, side3))
  {
    std::cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  Classifier(side1, side2, side3);
  Area(side1, side2, side3);
}
```

If you want a loop then you can do:

```
int main() {
  double side1, side2, side3;
  GetInput(side1, side2, side3);
  while (not ValidInput(side1, side2, side3)
  {
    std::cout << "invalid input. Try again.\n";
    GetInput(side1, side2, side3);
  }
  Classifier(side1, side2, side3);
  Area(side1, side2, side3);
}
```

Second loop example:

```
int main() {
  double side1 = 0.0, side2 = 0.0, side3 = 0.0;
  while (not ValidInput(side1, side2, side3)
  {
    GetInput(side1, side2, side3);
    if (not ValidInput(side1, side2, side3))
    {
      std::cout << "invalid input. Try again.\n";
    }
  }
  Classifier(side1, side2, side3);
  Area(side1, side2, side3);
}
```

Here GetInput is only called in one place, so you don't need to use a separate function.

Comment: For the loop snippet of code, is that assuming the input for the values as a separate function? As I'd like to have the error handling as a separate function and the input of values in the main function (unless of course this is bad practice! then please do inform me :))

Comment: @user2942863 yeah, I have GetInput as a function to get the input (it takes its arguments by reference, so it can set their values). I use a separate function so can just call it in two places rather than repeat its code in two places. However you can structure things differently. I'll add another example.

Answer (score 0):

It is an unconventional separation - but if you like, you can do it this way: the ExceptionHandling functions checks if "everything is Okay" and returns true, only if everything is okay:

```
bool ExceptionHandling(double side1, double side2, double side3)
{
    if (side1 < 1 || side2 < 1 || side3 < 1)
    {
        cout << "Error: All values must be greater than zero." << endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

double Classifier(double side1, double side2, double side3)
{
    if (side1 == side2 && side2 == side3)
    {
        cout << "This would be classified as an equilateral triangle." << endl;
    }

...

int main()
{
    double side1;
    cout << "Enter the longest side: ";
    cin >> side1;

        ...

    if(ExceptionHandling(side1, side2, side3)) {
        Classifier(side1, side2, side3);
        Area(side1, side2, side3);
    }
}
```

the calls to Classifier and Area are only done, if "everything is okay".

The naming now is a bit clumpsy, but you can change is easily, e.g. **ExceptionHandling** could be called **preconditionsMet**.